# Mysql trigger makes queries take unlimited time

Tags: mysql

I have a students table which includes following fields

`Student_Id int primary key`

`student_name varchar(50)`

`seat_number varchar(50)`

`level_id int foreign key`

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
`Student_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`student_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`level_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`seat_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `Relationship17` (`level_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `Relationship17` FOREIGN KEY (`level_id`) REFERENCES `levels` (`Level_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

**My goal**

To set unique values to seat_number field using query

```
FLOOR(rand() * 90000 + 10000)
```

And then to concat the result to a character based on level_id value.

So I create following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER seat_nu_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON students FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE x CHARACTER;
DECLARE cur cursor for select FLOOR(rand() * 90000 + 10000) from students;
open cur;
if NEW.level_id=1 THEN
set x = 'A';
ELSEIF
NEW.level_id=2 THEN
set x = 'B'; 
END IF;
getSeatNumber: LOOP
SET NEW.seat_number = concat(x,FLOOR(rand() * 90000 + 10000) );
END LOOP getSeatNumber;
CLOSE cur;
END;
```

**The problem**

When I insert any data to my table it doesn't inserted and the query takes unlimited time.

I cannot drop the trigger.

Comment: Your LOOP is perpetual - there is no LEAVE. PS1. LOOP not needed. PS2. Trigger opens cursor - for what? not needed too.

Comment: Your query runs forever because you have no way of breaking out of the loop. I don't actually see any reason to have the loop (or the cursor) in the trigger. Also there's no guarantee that `FLOOR(rand() * 90000 + 10000)` will return a unique value for each invocation of the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER seat_nu_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON students FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE valid_code TEXT;
DECLARE good_code BIT;

SET good_code = FALSE;

WHILE (NOT good_code) DO
    SET valid_code = CONCAT(
           (CASE NEW.level_id 
               WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
               WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
           END), 
           FLOOR(rand() * 90000 + 10000)
    );

    SET good_code = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM students WHERE seat_number = valid_code) = 0;
END WHILE;

SET NEW.seat_number = valid_code;
```

Try this one, it will generate a random number and check of the generated code exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER seat_nu_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON students 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.seat_number = CONCAT(CASE NEW.level_id WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
                                               WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
                                               END, FLOOR(rand() * 90000 + 10000) );
```

PS-1. If `level_id` is set to some other than `A` or `B` then `seat_number` will be set to NULL.

PS-2. `seat_number` length will be variable. Think about additional `LPAD()`.

PS-3. `seat_number` uniqueness is not guaranteed.